# Is it "easier" to find the optimal solution to the travelling salesman problem of size $n$ given that you have the optimal solution for size $n-1$?

Tags: combinatorics, computer-science, linear-programming, integer-programming, discrete-optimization

Provided with a complete graph $G = (V, E)$ where $|V| = n$, and an optimal solution that minimizes the travel cost for the subgraph $G' = (V', E')$, where $V' \subset V,\, |V'| = n-1$. Is it then computationally "easier" to find the optimal solution for the TSP of $G$?

Comment: A naive observation is that if there is an algorithm that takes time $t(n)$ to compute the optimal path in the $n$-vertex graph given the optimal path for some $(n-1)$-vertex subgraph, then there is an algorithm for TSP that takes time $\sum_{i = 1}^n t(i)$: solve the trivial instance and add nodes one by one.

Comment: @VilleSalo Thank you so much, that makes a lot of sense, don't know why I didn't think of that myself. Once again thanks.

Comment: No problem. My comment is just a general observation about NP-complete problems being unlikely to admit fast recursive algorithms (you can't many-one reduce to strictly smaller instances in polynomial time). There could in theory be something of interest to say about the specific situation of TSP, e.g. I don't know what the situations look like where the optimal solution to a size $n-1$ subproblem is particularly unhelpful.